# Can I corrupt data converting between []byte and string?

Tags: string, go, utf-8, character-encoding, slice

In Go, if I convert from a string -> []byte or conversely, from []byte -> string, could the data ever get corrupted.  For example, let's say I've defined:

```
fooBytes := []byte(fooString)
fooConvertedBack := string(fooBytes
fooBytesConvertedBack := []byte(fooConvertedBack)
```

Then could we get a case where data gets corrupted such that:

```
fooString != fooConvertedBack
fooBytes != fooBytesConvertedBack
```

I'm guessing the answer here is no.  I'm working with random arrays of bytes and I want to make sure that I won't corrupt data because, say for example, a golang string has a default character set which doesn't allow for completely random bytes.

Is it better to base64 encode the bytes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Cerise Limón wrote, it won't be corrupted. Converting between `string` and `[]byte` does not interpret the bytes, it just copies them as-are.

Do note however that if you would convert between `string` and `[]rune`, that might change the content becase as written in [Spec: Conversions to and from a string type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type):

> Converting a value of a string type to a slice of runes type yields a slice containing the individual Unicode code points of the string.

So this conversion decodes the runes (Unicode codepoints), and if the input `string` is not a valid UTF-8 encoded text, the Unicode replacement character `0xFFFD` will be used in such cases.

For example a `string` containing a single `0xff` byte is not a valid UTF-8 encoded text:

```
fooString := "\xff"
barString := string([]rune(fooString))
fmt.Println(fooString == barString)
fmt.Printf("%x %x", fooString, barString)
```

Outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cvjRfx4c1Xn)):

```
false
ff efbfbd
```

(Note: the hex `efbfdb` is the 3-byte UTF-8 encoded value of the Unicode replacement character `0xFFFD`.)

Answer (score 4):

No, the data will not be corrupted.  The conversions copy the bytes with no interpretation of what those bytes are. Here are the relevant sentences from the [specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type):

> Converting a slice of bytes to a string type yields a string whose successive bytes are the elements of the slice.

and

> Converting a value of a string type to a slice of bytes type yields a slice whose successive elements are the bytes of the string.

Go strings can contain arbitrary byte sequences.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a `string` to `[]byte` or vice versa, **SAFELY**.

From the [golang spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_types):

> A string value is a (possibly empty) sequence of bytes.

Also from the [official blog](https://blog.golang.org/strings):

> In Go, a string is in effect a read-only slice of bytes.